# Get a list of rows based on data from one to many(inverse) relationship in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have two models, Showtime and Movie. With the following relationship.

```
class Showtime extends Model{
    public function movie() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Movie');
    }
    //...
}
```

, and for the Movie

```
class Movie extends Model
{
    public function showtimes() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Showtime');
    }
    //...
}
```

Their table structure looks like this.

Showtime

- id
- movie_id
- date
- ...

Movie

- id
- title
- ...

My question is, how can I get a list of Movies that are listed in Showtimes after a certain date.

PS: Sorry about the title, I didn't know how to put it in short descriptive words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your relationship definition in the `Movie` model is wrong, it should be using `hasMany`:

```
class Movie extends Model
{
    public function showtimes() {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Showtime');
    }
}
```

With this part fixed, you should be able to query movies with a showtime after a given date like so:

```
$date = Carbon::now();
$movies = Movie::whereHas('showtimes', function ($query) use ($date) {
    $query->where('date', '>=', $date);
})->get();
```